# how to use spawn command in TCL

Tags: tcl, expect

I am using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!usr/bin/expect
#package require Expect


puts "Hello world"


spawn ssh xyz@172.31.112.182
expect -nocase "password:"
send "abc123\r"

puts "done"
```

while executing, it throws error

```
Hello world
invalid command name "spawn"
    while executing
"spawn ssh xyz@172.31.112.182"
    (file "temp.tcl" line 9)
```

whats the wrong in my code

Comment: How do you invoke your script?  If you call `tclsh script` then you need to uncomment the package require.

Answer (score 2):

remove '#' before package require Expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that while it is running in Tcl (I recognize that format of trace), the Expect package (which provides the `spawn` command) is absent for some reason. The first thing to do is to make the requirement for the Expect package explicit by uncommenting that `package require` line. That may be enough to fix your problem in itself, but if not it will complain about the package not being available. If it's not available, that means either that it just isn't installed, or that it's not being found. The former is... obvious to fix. :-) The latter is resolved by putting a line like this before that `package require`:

```
lappend auto_path /full/path/to/Expect/package/installation
```

Note that if you run the script with the *expect* program instead of the *tclsh* program, that `package require` will be done for you automatically. You're obviously not doing that…

Comment: install Expect from CMD as following: `teacup install Expect`

Answer (score 0):

Try running under tcl interpreter (!/usr/bin/tcl) and import Expect.

Comment: "!/usr/bin/tcl" is not a standard Tcl installation; there was a time when it was not uncommon for TclX.  "import Expect" is not a standard command in Tcl.

Comment: You "import" things in Tcl with `package require`. And when I compile Tcl from source and don't tell where it should go then tclsh it is installed as /usr/bin/tclsh.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed Expect on your PC?

Please run the following command on your PC to check if Expect is available.

#### $which expect

#### /usr/bin/expect

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get update -y
2. sudo apt-get install -y expect
3. which expect

Run the above commands respectively. If installed correctly, "which expect" will show "/usr/bin/expect" as an output. Run your script after installation,